# Generic классы в связи "многие ко многим"

Tags: c#, .net, архитектура, generics

Есть 3 класса которые реализуют связь данных "многие ко многим":

**PClient**

```
public class PClient
{
    public string Name;
    public int Number;

    public List<Phone> ProductCollection = new List<Phone>();
}
```

**PManufacturer**

```
public class PManufacturer
{
    public string Name;
    public string ProcessorManufacturer;

    public List<Phone> ProductCollection = new List<Phone>();
}
```

**Phone**

```
public class Phone: IDisposable
{
    public PClient Client;
    public PManufacturer Manuf;

    public DateTime ProdYear;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if(Client != null && Client.ProductCollection != null)
            Client.ProductCollection.Remove(this);

        if (Manuf != null && Manuf.ProductCollection != null)
            Manuf.ProductCollection.Remove(this);
    }
}
```

Так-же есть тройка классов которая в многом по логике и данным совпадают с этой тройкой.

**BClient**

```
public class BClient
{
    //Присутствует в PClient
    public string Name;
    //Отсутствует в PClient
    public int Weight;

    //Отличается от PClient переданным типом
    public List<Bicycle> ProductCollection = new List<Bicycle>();
}
```

**BManufacturer**

```
public class BManufacturer
{
    //Присутствует в PManufacturer
    public string Name;

    //Отсутствует в PManufacturer
    public string WheelManufact;

    //Отличается от PManufacturer переданным типом
    public List<Bicycle> ProductCollection = new List<Bicycle>();
}
```

**Bicycle**

```
public class Bicycle
{
    //Присутствует в Phone
    public BClient Client;
    public BManufacturer Manuf;

    //Отсутствует в Phone
    public int NumberOfWheel;

    //Совпадает с Phone
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (Client != null && Client.ProductCollection != null)
            Client.ProductCollection.Remove(this);

        if (Manuf != null && Manuf.ProductCollection != null)
            Manuf.ProductCollection.Remove(this);
    }
}
```

т.к. все эти классы попарно во многом похожи, все сходства желательно вынести в базовые классы.

**Вопрос: Как я могу это сделать?**

Сам пытался реализовать базовые классы через Generic но постоянно нарываюсь на ошибку вроде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вашу ошибку контрразведчики вымарали цензурой, сжали и выложили в виде нечитаемой картинки. Выйдите из под колпака и опубликуйте текст сообщения ошибки. Попытку с Generic желательно тоже.

Comment: Так вы покажите, что пытались. И можно ошибки текстом, а не мелким скрином показывать, а то глаза можно сломать разглядывая что там

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы значительно переусложняете. дело в том, что в вашей реализации вряд ли нужен Dispose (во всяком случае для этих классов и в том виде, в котором он реализован). Dispose нужен для освобождения ресурсов, у вас же их нет. Без Dispose ваш код можно свести к такому:

```
public abstract class Base<T>            
{
    public string Name;

    public List<T> ProductCollection = new List<T>();
}

public abstract class BaseProduct<TClient, TManufacturer, TProd> 
    where TClient : Base<TProd>
    where TManufacturer : Base<TProd>
{
    public TClient Client;

    public TManufacturer Manuf;

    public DateTime ProdYear;            
}

public class Phone : BaseProduct<PClient, PManufacturer, Phone>
{

}

public class Bicycle : BaseProduct<BClient, BManufacturer, Bicycle>
{
    //Отсутствует в Phone
    public int NumberOfWheel;
}

public class PClient : Base<Phone>
{
    public int Number;
}

public class PManufacturer : Base<Phone>
{
    public string ProcessorManufacturer;
}

public class BClient : Base<Bicycle>
{
    //Отсутствует в PClient
    public int Weight;
}

public class BManufacturer : Base<Bicycle>
{
    //Отсутствует в PManufacturer
    public string WheelManufact;
}
```

Если же IDisposable прям нужен кровь из носу, то всё будет несколько сложнее, и тогда код становится менее естественным:

```
public abstract class AbstractProduct
{

}

public abstract class Base<T>
            where T: AbstractProduct
{
    public string Name;

    public List<T> ProductCollection = new List<T>();
}

public abstract class BaseProduct<TClient, TManufacturer, TProd>  : AbstractProduct, IDisposable
    where TClient: Base<TProd>
    where TManufacturer: Base<TProd>
    where TProd : AbstractProduct
{
    public TClient Client;

    public TManufacturer Manuf;

    public DateTime ProdYear;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        var that = this as TProd;
        if (Client != null && Client.ProductCollection != null)
            Client.ProductCollection.Remove(that);

        if (Manuf != null && Manuf.ProductCollection != null)
            Manuf.ProductCollection.Remove(that);
    }
}
```

Comment: Удалось реализовать ваш ответ на структуре классов моего проекта. Вчера весь вечер провозился. Спасибо за ответ, очень помогли!